# Problem installing Ubuntu 18.04 after the dual boot

Tags: nvidia-geforce

My screen goes black the moment I try to boot from my USB. I have attached the image of the problem.

[image]

The issue is the screen automatically goes blank after displaying those 4 options. I have no idea on how to deal with this problem. I have a Lenovo Yoga 720. It does have a graphic card- NVIDIA 1050 ti. I have disabled this graphic card though.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding :

When you boot from the the pendrive you are welcomed by the black menu list which says

- Try Ubuntu
- Install Ubuntu
- OEM Install(for manufacturers)
- Check Disks for Defects

This is very normal if you have booted from the UEFI Option then you are greeted with a black background menu and when you boot under the legacy option you are greated with a purple background menu.

hope that helps.